# Getting the address of a function in C?

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, rootkit

I'm getting a segfault when running this code as root in userspace. I don't understand why. I believe I have a rootkit and I want to check if the addresses are the same as the ones as in /boot/System.map-3.2.0-4-amd64

```
unsigned long hex;
unsigned long **sys_call_table;

for(hex = 0xffffffff810f8989; hex < 0xffffffff8160e370; hex += sizeof(void *))
{
    sys_call_table = (unsigned long **)hex;

    if(sys_call_table[3] == (unsigned long *)0xffffffff810f8989)
    {
        puts("sys_close's address has not been replaced by the rootkit");
    }
}
```

cat /boot/System.map-3.2.0-4-amd64 | grep "string you want"

```
ffffffff81401200 R sys_call_table
ffffffff810f9f9e T sys_read         // sys_call_table[0]
ffffffff810fa009 T sys_write        // sys_call_table[1]
ffffffff810f950d T sys_open         // sys_call_table[2]
ffffffff810f8989 T sys_close        // sys_call_table[3]
ffffffff8160e370 D loops_per_jiffy
```

Comment: Are you sure that `sizeof(unsigned long)` is equal to 8 in your case?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I'm using x86-64 and it is 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running from `root` is not enough - the problem is that you run it in `user space` - run it in the `kernel space`, as a kernel module, for example. Although having `root` privileges is enough for invoking system calls you cannot access the table - in `user space` you can only access allocated memory to you.

Comment: What do you mean, syscalls are accessible from the userspace, that's the whole point.

Comment: I mean you can not access random parts of memory like OP does if it was not given to you.

Comment: Ok but elaine thinks those are valid addresses because they are supposed to be addresses of the systems calls. In fact, they are not because addresses in System.map are only valid in the kernel space and not in the process space. Which is more or less what you are saying ... I guess

Comment: Syscalls are available from userspace in the sense that userspace code can invoke syscalls, but NOT in the sense that they can access the table.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that `root` could access anything.

Comment: Sure, root passes any privilege check. But a process running in user-space always has its own mapped memory area. Trying to access arbitrary addresses in kernel memory isn't a privilege problem, it's a memory mapping problem.